# how to send http 101 just with one CRLF

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh

There is an SSH client application that after requesting HTTP GET to an http server, should receive HTTP 101 switching protocol and a header for "Protocol Version Exchange".

The RFC 4253 -- section [4.2. Protocol Version Exchange](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4253#section-4.2) indicates that the header format MUST be

```bash
SSH-protoversion-softwareversion<CR><LF>
```

example

```bash
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.5\r\n
```

and doing so in pytong3 as follow

```py
...
...
class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(101)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/plain")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes("SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.5", "utf-8"))
...
...
```

the response header will be (*what the SSH client receives*)

```bash
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.5\r\n\r\n
```

and therefor SSH client application closes the connection.

How to properly set just one `CRLF` for the header or remove the second one ?

it should be and start with `SSH-`

```bash
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.5\r\n
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `end_headers()` and manually write the headers along with the protocol version so you can have full control

```py
def do_GET(self):
  self.send_response(101)
  self.send_header("Content-type", "text/plain")
  headers = self.headers.items()
  header_str = ''.join(f"{key}: {value}\r\n" for key, value in headers)
  protocol_version_str = "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.5\r\n"
  response = f"{header_str}{protocol_version_str}".encode('utf-8')
  self.wfile.write(response)
```

Comment: I never coded python -- which `function` can I use to have full control?

Comment: I added code snippet to my answer

Comment: according the RFE the header should start with `SSH-`  so I removed this part of your code `header_str` and yet the head has three CRLF `\r\n\r\n\r\n` -- the first one you added the rest are added and header again - removing yours , yet the app gets `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.5\r\n\r\n`

Comment: I think the `wfile.write` adds the CRLF and other functions should be used , what else can we use  instead of `wfile.write` ?

Comment: I see no reason for `write()` to add anything. Just remove CRLF from `protocol_version_str`